# Deep Linking no funciona en una aplicación cerrada Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

estoy programando una aplicación en expo con react navigation y el problema que me tiene estancado actualmente es que simple y sencillamente no logro que el link abra correctamente en la aplicacion cerrada, es decir el link funciona correctamente solo cuando la aplicacion está abierta o en segundo plano pero en la aplicación cerrasa lo unico que pasa es que solo se abre la pagina inicial.

Mi codigo es el siguiente :

```js
const prefix = Linking.makeUrl('/');

export default function App() {
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);
  const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState();
  
  const ref = useRef();

  const { getInitialState } = useLinking(ref, {
    prefixes: [prefix],
    config: {
      CambiarContrasena: "CambiarContrasena/:code"
    }
  });
    const sessiontype = useSelector(state => state.userdata.sessiontype)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()


    useEffect(() => {
        detectsession()
        getInitialState()
          .catch((error) => { console.log(error)})
          .then(state => {
            if (state !== undefined) {
              setInitialState(state);
            }
            setIsReady(true);
        })
    }, [ getInitialState ]);

    const detectsession = async()=>{
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user-token')
        if(token == null){
            dispatch({type : 'OnUserSession', payload: {sessiontype: 1}})
        } else {
            dispatch({type : 'OnUserSession', payload: {sessiontype: 2}})
        }

    }

    if (!isReady) {
      return null;
    }
    if(sessiontype == 0){
        return(
            <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
            </View>
        )
    }else if(sessiontype == 1){
        return (
            <NavigationContainer initialState={initialState} ref={ref}>
                <Auth.Navigator headerMode='none'>
                    <Auth.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
                    <Auth.Screen name="VerificationCode" component={VerificationCode} />
                    <Auth.Screen name="CambiarContrasena" component={CambiarContraseña} />
                    <Auth.Screen name="ReestablecerContraseña" component={ReestablecerContraseña} />
                </Auth.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        )
    }
}

Espero que puedan ayudarme
```

Edito: Acabo de hacer un console.log a getinitialstatus y por alguna razón que desconozco siempre regresa undefined

Answer (score 1):

Luego de pasar una noche en vela probando diferentes formas de resolver este problema finalmente encontré la solución y resulta que es bastante tonta

cambiar esto:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        detectsession()
        getInitialState()
          .catch((error) => { console.log(error)})
          .then(state => {
            if (state !== undefined) {
              setInitialState(state);
            }
            setIsReady(true);
        })
    }, [ getInitialState ]);

    const detectsession = async()=>{
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user-token')
        if(token == null){
            dispatch({type : 'OnUserSession', payload: {sessiontype: 1}})
        } else {
            dispatch({type : 'OnUserSession', payload: {sessiontype: 2}})
        }

    }
```

por esto :

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        detectsession()
    }, [ ]);

    const detectsession = async()=>{
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user-token')
        if(token == null){
            dispatch({type : 'OnUserSession', payload: {sessiontype: 1}})
            const state = await getInitialState()
            if (state !== undefined) {
              setInitialState(state);
            }
            setIsReady(true);
        } else {
            dispatch({type : 'OnUserSession', payload: {sessiontype: 2}})
        }

    }
```

Y por alguna razon requerir getInitialUrl en el conponente raiz

```js
function App() {

    useEffect(() => {
      initialstate()
  }, [ ]);

  const initialstate = async()=>{
    const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();

  }
```

Comment: interesante, he trabajado con react native pero no habia esuchado nunca el deep linking, en tu caso que linkeas o como funciona...me causa curiosidad

Comment: En este caso estoy redirigiendo al usuario de la web a una pantalla especifica de la aplicación (EN este caso vendría a ser la de recuperación de contraseña)

Comment: entendido, gracias